# httpd service not starting after installation of mod_dav_svn module in RHEL 6

Tags: linux, apache, svn, rhel, mod-dav-svn

I tried to configure web access to Subversion under Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.7 (Santiago). I installed httpd and mod_dav_svn using yum. But after installing the mod_dav_svn module, the httpd service is showing errors:

> Starting httpd: httpd: Syntax error on line 217 of /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf: Syntax error on line 2 of /etc/httpd/conf.d/subversion.conf: Cannot load /etc/httpd/modules/mod_dav_svn.so into server: /etc/httpd/modules/mod_dav_svn.so: undefined symbol: dav_register_provider

Can someone help to resolve the issue?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like another missing library issue. Verify that you have subversion library installed.

```
svn --version
```

if not,

```
sudo yum install subversion
```

To check further for missing libraries, Check the output of following commands

```
 ldd  /etc/httpd/modules/mod_dav_svn.so
```

Hope it helps.